# Laravel 5.4 Use request and use Illuminate\Http\Request; cant work at the same time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I cant get my namespaces to work at the same time . What seems to be the problem ? If i used the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and comment out the `use Request` . My code on function 1 works . When i use function 2 it produces an error ( `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::file() should not be called statically` )

When i use `use Request;` and comment out `use Illuminate\Http\Request`  then use function 1, i get this error(`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::hasFile()` ) . And when i use function 2 the code works just fine .

Namespaces used :

```
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Request;
```

Function 1 :

```
public function PharmaaddList(Request $request)
  {
    if($request->hasFile('medicines')){

        #Code Here
    }
}
```

Function 2:

```
 public function PharmaImageUpload(Request $request)
{
    $fileupload = Request::file('fileupload');
    #Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alias one of the classes to use both in the same file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as RequestFacade;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

...

public function PharmaImageUpload(Request $request)
{
    $fileupload = RequestFacade::file('fileupload');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only one both of them classes or you need to alias one of the classes to use both in the same file

like this

```
    public function PharmaaddList(Request $request)
      {
        if($request->input('medicines')){

            #Code Here`enter code here`
        }
    }


public function PharmaImageUpload(Request $request)
{
    $fileupload = $request->input('fileupload');
    #Code Here
}
```